# Inheritance causes function to be executed so many times Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning JavaScript and I got stuck creating a function to minimize a window. The problem is that this functions seems to stack in itself so many times.

Gere is my principal function :

```
function displayChatWindow(user, status, avatar, id){
    var template = _.template($("#windowTemplate").html(), {userName: user, userStatus: status, userAvatar: avatar, userId: id});
    stackingWidth = stackingWidth - boxWidth;
    console.log(stackingWidth);
    $("body").prepend(template);
    $(".messages-container").slimScroll({
        height: '200',
        size: '10px',
        position: 'right',
        color: '#535a61',
        alwaysVisible: false,
        distance: '0',
        railVisible: true,
        railColor: '#222',
        railOpacity: 0.3,
        wheelStep: 10,
        disableFadeOut: false,
        start: "bottom"     
    });
     $("#" + id).css({
        top: absoluteY,
        left: stackingWidth
    });
    $(".minimize-others").on("click", displayOthersChat);
    $(".chat input, .chat textarea").on("focus", cleanInputs);
    $(".chat input, .chat textarea").on("blur", setInputs);
}
```

This function receives some parameters and with a template creates the chat window. At the end it applies the function to minimize the window (`displayOthersChat`) and load plugins and stuff for each window.

My `displayOtherChats` function:

```
function displayOthersChat(e){
        /*e.preventDefault();*/
    var This = $(this).parent().parent();
    var minimize = This;
    if(!This.hasClass("draggable")){
        This.animate({
            top: windowHeight - boxHeight - 20
        });
        This.addClass("draggable");
        This.draggable({handle: ".header"});
        var timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
            This.find(".minimize").toggleClass("rotate");
        }, 500);
    }else{
        This.draggable("destroy");
        This.removeClass("draggable");
        var timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
            This.find(".minimize").toggleClass("rotate");
        }, 500);
        This.animate({
            top: absoluteY
        });
    }
     /*return false;*/
}
```

This seems to work really well. If I open my first window it displays and also minimizing the window works. When I open another window, the last window works correctly but the first window opens when I try to minimize it.

It seems that it calls the function twice, and if I open a third window, the first window calls the function three times.

I actually don't know whats going on, I will appreciate if you guys could help me. I also leave a link so you guys can see whats going on: http://s3.enigmind.com/jgonzalez/nodeChat.

Comment: What does this have to do with OOP and inheritance? I don't see any constructor functions or inheritance anywhere. Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo which replicates the problem. We will be able to provide better help then.

Comment: Well actually i am learning so i thought it was something about oop or inheritance :/ ahahahah

Comment: So I guess the problem is that you are binding the same event handler over and over again. `$(".minimize-others").on("click", displayOthersChat);` will bind `displayOthersChat` to all *existing* elements with class `minimize-others`. You might only want to bind it to the window that was just created, maybe `template.find('.minimize-others').on(...)`. Same for the other functions.

Comment: exactly that was my error, i just thit this $("#" + id).find(".minimize").on("click", displayOthersChat); and now is working correctly i thinks it was applying the function to all the elements in the Dom or something like that.

Comment: As I said, `$(".minimize-others")` selects **all** elements with class `minimize-others`.

Comment: @FelixKling thank you for taking the time to read the code i appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are binding the same event handler to the same elements over and over again.

`$(".minimize-others").on("click", displayOthersChat);` will bind `displayOthersChat` to **all existing elements** with class `minimize-others`. `.on` always **adds** event handlers, it does not replace them. So if you call `displayChatWindow` multiple times, you are binding the event handler to the `.minimize-others` elements multiple times.

You only want to bind the handler to the window that was just created, for example:

```
// create reusable jQuery object from HTML string.
var $template = $(template).prependTo('body');
// instead of $("body").prepend(template);
// ...
$template.find('.minimize-others').on('click', displayOthersChat);
```

Same goes for the other event handlers.

---

Alternatively, you could bind the event handler **once**, *outside* of the function and use [*event delegation*](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to capture the event:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.minimize-others', displayOthersChat);
```